# Why does InnoDB block more records in case of a secondary index?

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb

I'm using MySQL InnoDB tables and trying to understand the reasons for some row-level locking in the case of an index range scan. I found that an extra index record (out of range) may be locked depending on the uniqueness of the index used. See the example below (verified in version 8.0.18).

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  a INT NOT NULL,
  b INT NOT NULL,
  c CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (a),
  UNIQUE KEY (b)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1,1,'A'), (3,3,'B'), (5,5,'C'), (7,7,'D'), (9,9,'E');
```

#### Test case 1

Session 1:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE a < 2 FOR UPDATE;
```

Session 2:

```
DELETE FROM foo WHERE a = 3;  -- Success
```

#### Test case 2

This uses the original rows of the table with the deleted record returned.

Session 1:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE b < 2 FOR UPDATE;
```

Session 2:

```
DELETE FROM foo WHERE b = 3;  -- Blocks
```

Locking the secondary index record with b = 3 in the second test case looks unnecessary.

Why does InnoDB block the next index entry to the right of the scanned range in case of a secondary index? Is there any practical reason for this?
Can someone give an example of a problem that could happen if the record with b = 3 is not blocked in the second test case?

Comment: File a bug at bugs.mysql.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the answer. In short, there are no significant reasons for such additional locking in the second test case. When a locking read of a secondary index range is performed, sufficient locks are set, but not a necessary minimum. Thus, extra locks are set only because it was easier for some InnoDB programmers to write code. Who cares about extra locks if everything works for the most part?

I posted a bug report about this issue: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=98639
Unfortunately, their employee does not want to register this bug. He does not understand my arguments and comes up with erroneous explanations. He made my last arguments private and stopped responding.

I also asked about this issue in the official forum and received the following answer: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,684356,684482
In short, significant efforts are required to fix this bug. But since this is a very small and insignificant bug (more precisely, a performance issue), they do not want to fix it yet. However, in version 8.0.18, they fixed a similar problem for the clustered index, and it took them more than a month.

I'm very surprised that optimizing such a simple single-level scanning algorithm takes so much time and is so difficult for the MySQL team.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Barmar already mentioned it is so because MySQL is setting a GAP or a Next-key lock. I assume that you are using the default innodb isolation level `REPEATABLE READ`

The MySQL documentation says:

> For locking reads (SELECT with FOR UPDATE or LOCK IN SHARE MODE), UPDATE, and DELETE statements, locking depends on whether the statement uses a unique index with a unique search condition, or a range-type search condition.
>
> - For a unique index with a unique search condition, InnoDB locks only the index record found, not the gap before it.
> - For other search conditions, InnoDB locks the index range scanned, using gap locks or next-key locks to block insertions by other sessions into the gaps covered by the range. For information about gap locks and next-key locks, see Section 14.7.1, “InnoDB Locking”.

See:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html#isolevel_repeatable-read

At the moment i'm looking for info on how the gap lock is set, but I also got this info, and I guess it is helpfull information:

Keep in mind that the lock is based on a internal index because the column that you are using in your criteria is not uniquely indexed.

> A gap lock is a lock on a gap **between index records**, **or a lock on the gap *before the first* or *after the last index* record**
>
> Gap locks in InnoDB are “purely inhibitive”, which means that their only purpose is to prevent other transactions from inserting to the gap. Gap locks can co-exist. A gap lock taken by one transaction does not prevent another transaction from taking a gap lock on the same gap. There is no difference between shared and exclusive gap locks. They do not conflict with each other, and they perform the same function.
>
> Gap locking can be disabled explicitly. **This occurs if you change the transaction isolation level to READ COMMITTED or enable the innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog system variable** (which is now deprecated). Under these circumstances, gap locking is disabled for searches and index scans and is used only for foreign-key constraint checking and duplicate-key checking.
>
> There are also other effects of using the READ COMMITTED isolation level or enabling innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog. Record locks for nonmatching rows are released after MySQL has evaluated the WHERE condition. For UPDATE statements, InnoDB does a “semi-consistent” read, such that it returns the latest committed version to MySQL so that MySQL can determine whether the row matches the WHERE condition of the UPDATE.

see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-gap-locks

Comment: Gap locking is not related to my question. A gap lock cannot block index deletion, but only index insertion. In the second test example, the index record with b = 3 is locked (with or without its gap, depending on the isolation level). The question is why the index record is locked itself. This happens with any level of isolation.  
Suppose we use the RR isolation level. Why does InnoDB use a next-key lock instead of a gap lock for the record with b = 3 in the second test case?

Comment: I've been looking all day to explain this, but I'm a bit stuck for now. You could try looking into the `innodb (lock) monitor` this could give some valuable information. Ive tried but had a hard time understanding the output. Good luck! Please let me know if you figure it out. :) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-enabling-monitors.html

Comment: The lock monitor only allows to see what locks are set. But it does not explain why they were set, and does not explain what problem each of the locks solves.